# Service isn't getting intent

Tags: android, service, path, media-player

To play an audio file from an SD card I'm passing a file called path to a service to start a mediaplayer playing path.

This is passing it

```
private void playAudio(String url) throws Exception{
     Intent music = new Intent(this,MusicService.class);
     music.putExtra("paths", url);
     startService(music);   
}
```

This is my service class receiving the intent.

```
class MusicService extends Service implements OnCompletionListener {
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
 String musicFile;


  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
     mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  }

  @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       Bundle e = intent.getExtras();
       musicFile= e.getString("paths"); 
      try {
         mediaPlayer.prepare(); 
         mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicFile);
       } catch (IllegalArgumentException i) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          i.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IllegalStateException i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            i.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
      if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
      {             
        mediaPlayer.start();             
      } 
      return START_STICKY; 
}
```

My problem is the mediaplayer isn't playing the path. I'm not sure if it's not receiving the file from the SD or not starting for some reason.

Comment: just alter prepare() and setDataSource() for media player.

Comment: What? i don't understand those specifications are perfect

Comment: After setting  dataSource,you are forcefully called to prepare method.  Incase of if you are using mediaplyer like this, player=MediaPlayer.create(.....),No need to prepare it.

Answer (score 0):

To help you debug, add some Toasts here and there in your service:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Putting it strategically, this will help you see if the service is started correctly, if the service launches its methods, etc. Pinpointing errors is even more important than fixing them.